# Getting full webpack development server output from React development server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

When I create a React application with `create-react-app` and then run `npm run start`, React will start its own development server which is based on WDS in the background, and give me the following output:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view xyz in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://172.20.240.1:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

The trouble is, the output is then silent.  Webpack gives you loads of extra output about what its doing.  How can I get the React development server to give me the full verbose Webpack development server output?